# bibnewpage option using apacite not working

Tags: page-breaking, apa-style, apa6

I am having difficulty with getting the references to show on a new page using apacite.  According to the documentation the bibnewpage option should do it, but it is not happening.  It is displaying the citation and references fin, just not showing it on a new page.  I am also have the natbibapa option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{author99,
title = {A fine title},
year = {1899},
author = {An Author and Another Bauthor and Yeta Cauthor},
journal = {Madness}
}
@article{author05,
title = {The best title},
year = {1905},
author = {An Author and More Dauthors and Whois Thisauthor and Heis Thatauthor},
journal = {Insanity}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage[natbibapa,bibnewpage]{apacite}

\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}
citation commands
\citep Parenthetical citation
\citet Text citation
\citeauthor Author only (text citation)
\citeyear Year only (no parentheses)
\citeyearpar Year citation (with parentheses)
\citealp Parenthetical citation without the parentheses
\citealt Text citation without the parentheses
\citenum Number of the reference
\nocite No citation, only reference list entry
\Citep etc. Capitalized citation
\citep* etc. Full author lists
\shortcites Short author lists
\defcitealias Dene alias (e.g., DSM-IV )
\citepalias Parenthetical citation of alias
\citetalias Text citation of alias
\citetext Arbitrary text within citation parentheses
\end{comment}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}


\title{Title of Paper}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\author{Name}
\authornote{This is an assignment for .}
\abstract{abstract text }
\date{\today} % or \date{24Jan11} for example


The time has come for all good men to come to the aid of their country test
 \citep{author05}.  According to \citet{author05}, the time has come for all good men to come to the aid of their country.



\bibliography{./test}
\end{document}
...
```

Note, according to the APA 6 manual (p. 36), "Start the reference list on a new page.  The word References should appear in uppercase and lowercase letters, centered.  Double-space all reference entries.  APA publishes references in hanging indent format, meaning that the first line of each reference is set flush left and subsequent lines are indented."  Using the apa6e and apacite with the bibnewpage option does not produce a reference list on a new page.  It puts the reference list after the last paragraph on the same page.  I tried to enter a \newpage before the bibliography , but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `apacite.sty`: if the `natbibapa` package option is not used, the `bibnewpage` option behaves as expected but, as soon as `natbibapa` (which internally loads `natbib`) is used, the bibliographical section doesn't start in a new page.

One way to have the bibliographical section starting in a new page would be to use

```
\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography{\clearpage\oldthebibliography}
```

in the preamble of the document, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{apa6e}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa,bibnewpage]{myapacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{author99,
title = {A fine title},
year = {1899},
author = {An Author and Another Bauthor and Yeta Cauthor},
journal = {Madness}
}
@article{author05,
title = {The best title},
year = {1905},
author = {An Author and More Dauthors and Whois Thisauthor and Heis Thatauthor},
journal = {Insanity}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography{\clearpage\oldthebibliography}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of Paper}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\author{Name}
\authornote{This is an assignment for .}
\abstract{abstract text }
\date{\today} % or \date{24Jan11} for example


The time has come for all good men to come to the aid of their country test
 \citep{author05}.  According to \citet{author05}, the time has come for all good men to come to the aid of their country.

\bibliography{./test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice hack!  that worked!  How would one go about reporting the bug to apacite developers?  Is this it?  Thanks for the quick replies guys and the welcome.  I am new to latex.  It seems like a great langauge.  The other thing I noticed is that the citation on the first line goes out into the margin a little bit instead of wrapping to the next line.  Did you see that?

Comment: if you take out the word test.  ...aid of their country \citep{author05}

Comment: @Dan You can report the bug directly to the package author/maintainer; normally the package documentation contains the e-mail to contact the author. Regarding the wrapping issue, I cannot test it right now (I don't have a LaTeX system at hand), but I'll try it as soon as I can (you can also ask a follow-up question to this one if you consider it is worthy). As a side note, since my answer seems to have solved your problem, please consider accepting it; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: Wait I just realized that the title page and abstract seem to be cut off now.   Is that happening to you?

Comment: it also seems to work to just put \clearpage above the \bibliography but I have still lost the title page, abstract page, and title at the top of the first page after the abstract page now.

Comment: How would I undo that renewcommand? I can't seem to get the title page and abstract pages to come back even with a reinstall.  thanks

Comment: even when I remove apacite altogether the title page and abstract pages are still gone.  odd.  something seems to have happened to apa6e

Comment: @Dan I've answered the other question you opened regrading the new problem. On a side note, maybe I am mistaken but it seemed to me that you had accepted this answer some hours ago and then you un-accepted it. If this is so, may I ask you why?

Comment: Oh, sorry I wasn't sure if it was resolved or not because of the title page issue.  I emailed Erik Meijer about the reference page issue.  I also installed some updates, so I wasn't sure if the new problems was due to that.  I suspected it was something like a missing line.  I didn't recall having that line before.  Thanks again for your help